# Xamarin.Forms: OKTA SSO integration with SAML

Tags: xamarin.forms, single-sign-on, okta, okta-api

In our Xamarin.forms app, we want to support SSO with OKTA. By using link https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/05/01/add-authentication-xamarin-openid-connect, we were able to implement SSO feature but using "OpenId Connect" (not SAML).

My question here is can we integrate OKTA SSO with SAML in Xamarin.Forms? If 'Yes' any help link is appreciated here.

Comment: SAML2 is a web single sign on protocol and is not meant to be used by a mobile application.

For a mobile application you want both authentication at the mobile app level, as well as a bearer token for calls to backend APIS. OpenID Connect is the solution for that. So you should set up your application to use OpenID Connect and then use a token issuer that can authenticate users through SAML2.0

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT, I agree with you that SAML is something not for Mobile, but below links https://developer.okta.com/use_cases/mobile/okta_mobile_connect , https://github.com/okta/okta-mobile-connect confused me. These link say SAML can be used for mobile App as well.

Comment: did anyone implement any concrete implementation of saml sso in mobile using okta yet? any luck?